# Continuously update marker when location changed on Android - Not happening

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm trying to implement an simple navigation app using Google maps. Initially I developed a code for marking two Geo points on map and showing route between them. Now I am trying to move the first marker towards second marker (destination) based on users location.
My first marker is the device's location and the second is fetched from db through api.

For this I used LocationListener and implemented code in onLocationChanged. The problem is onLocationChanged is not getting fired and marker is not moving based on user location.Marker moves only on loading the app every single time.
Here is my code.

```
  public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback,
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

private GoogleMap mMap;
ArrayList<LatLng> MarkerPoints = new ArrayList<>();
GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
Location mLastLocation;
Marker mCurrLocationMarker1,mCurrLocationMarker2;
LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

FrameLayout mainFrameLayout;
Snackbar snackbar;

private static final int PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE = 1;
String stringIMEI = "",stringLatitudeOrigin = "",stringLongitudeOrigin = "",
        stringLatitudeDest = "",stringLongitudeDest = "",stringCurrentDate = "";
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

    sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("sharedPreferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    System.out.println("Current time =&gt; "+c.getTime());

    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    stringCurrentDate = df.format(c.getTime());
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    mainFrameLayout = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainFrameLayout);

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        checkLocationPermission();
    }

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), android.Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        requestPermissions(new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE},
                PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE);
    }else {
        TelephonyManager mngr = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        stringIMEI = mngr.getDeviceId().toString();
    }
}
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            buildGoogleApiClient();
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }
    }
    else {
        buildGoogleApiClient();
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }
    if (checkLocationPermission()) {
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        mMap.setTrafficEnabled(false);
        mMap.setIndoorEnabled(false);
        mMap.setBuildingsEnabled(true);
        mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(new CameraPosition.Builder()
                .target(mMap.getCameraPosition().target).zoom(17).bearing(30).tilt(45).build()));
    }
}
private String getUrl(LatLng origin, LatLng dest) {
    String str_origin = "origin=" + origin.latitude + "," + origin.longitude;
    String str_dest = "destination=" + dest.latitude + "," + dest.longitude;
    String key = "key=AIzaSyDkuXKvLCxtKs1jkXRXyt5Kk1Qv3fUe7mU";
    String parameters = str_origin + "&"  + str_dest + "&"  + key;//+ waypoints + "&"
    String output = "json";
    String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/" + output + "?" + parameters;
    return url;
}
private class FetchUrl extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String data = "";
        try {
            HttpConnection http = new HttpConnection();
            data = http.downloadUrl(url[0]);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            Log.d("Background Task", e.toString());
        }
        return data;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        new ParserTask().execute(result);
    }
}
 private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<List<HashMap<String, String>>>> {
    // Parsing the data in non-ui thread
    @Override
    protected List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> doInBackground(
            String... jsonData) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        JSONObject jObject;
        List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = null;
        try {
            jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);
            if (!jObject.equals("")){
                //save route api call
                SaveRouteVolleyRequest(jObject.toString());
                }
            DirectionsJSONParser parser = new DirectionsJSONParser();
            routes = parser.parse(jObject);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return routes;
    }
    // Executes in UI thread, after the parsing process
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> result) {
        ArrayList<LatLng> points = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
        PolylineOptions lineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
        lineOptions.width(8);
        lineOptions.color(Color.RED);
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        // Traversing through all the routes
        for(int i=0;i<result.size();i++){
            // Fetching i-th route
            List<HashMap<String, String>> path = result.get(i);
            // Fetching all the points in i-th route
            for(int j=0;j<path.size();j++){
                HashMap<String,String> point = path.get(j);
                double lat = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lat"));
                double lng = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lng"));
                LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng);
                points.add(position);
            }
            // Adding all the points in the route to LineOptions
            lineOptions.addAll(points);

        }
        // Drawing polyline in the Google Map for the i-th route
        if(points.size()!=0)mMap.addPolyline(lineOptions);
    }
}

protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);
    mLocationRequest.setExpirationDuration(1000);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
    mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(0.1f);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
    }
}
 @Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) { }

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    mLastLocation = location;
    mMap.clear();
    if (mCurrLocationMarker1 != null) {
        mCurrLocationMarker1.remove();
    }
    //Place current location marker
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
    stringLatitudeOrigin = String.valueOf(location.getLatitude());
    stringLongitudeOrigin = String.valueOf(location.getLongitude());
    mCurrLocationMarker1 = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("Your device").draggable(true)
            .visible(true).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker)).anchor(0.5f, 0.5f));

    if (isConnectingToInternet(MainActivity.this) == true) {
        GetLocationVolleyRequest();
    }else{snackbar = Snackbar.make(mainFrameLayout, "No Internet Connection,Please Verify", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
        snackbar.show();
    }
    //move map camera
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng,13.0f));
    //stop location updates
    if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
    }
}
 @Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) { }

public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION = 99;
public boolean checkLocationPermission(){
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
        }
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION: {
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                        == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
                        buildGoogleApiClient();
                    }
                    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                    mMap.setTrafficEnabled(false);
                    mMap.setIndoorEnabled(false);
                    mMap.setBuildingsEnabled(true);
                    mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
                    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(new CameraPosition.Builder()
                            .target(mMap.getCameraPosition().target).zoom(17).bearing(30).tilt(45).build()));
                }
            }else {
                snackbar = Snackbar.make(mainFrameLayout, "permission denied", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                snackbar.show();
            }
            return;
        }
        case PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE : {
            if (requestCode == PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                TelephonyManager mngr = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
                stringIMEI = mngr.getDeviceId().toString();
            }else {
                snackbar = Snackbar.make(mainFrameLayout, "permission denied", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                snackbar.show();
            }
        } 
    }
}
 public void GetLocationVolleyRequest(){
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Constants.LOCATIONAPI_URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);
                        if (json.getString("success").equals("1")) {
                            if (json.has("id")) {
                                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                                editor.putString("device_id", json.getString("id"));
                                editor.commit();
                            }else {
                                snackbar = Snackbar.make(mainFrameLayout, json.getString("msg"), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                                snackbar.getView().setBackgroundColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark);
                                TextView mainTextView = (TextView) (snackbar.getView()).findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
                                mainTextView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                                snackbar.show();
                            }
                            if (json.has("latitude")) {
                                stringLatitudeDest = json.getString("latitude");
                                stringLongitudeDest = json.getString("longitude");

                                snackbar = Snackbar.make(mainFrameLayout, "Other Device -> Lat : " + stringLatitudeDest + " Lng : " +
                                                stringLongitudeDest, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                                snackbar.getView().setBackgroundColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark);
                                TextView mainTextView = (TextView) (snackbar.getView()).findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
                                mainTextView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                                snackbar.show();

                                mCurrLocationMarker2 = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(stringLatitudeDest),
                                        Double.parseDouble(stringLongitudeDest))).title("Other device").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker)));

                                MarkerPoints.add(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(stringLatitudeOrigin), Double.parseDouble(stringLongitudeOrigin)));
                                MarkerPoints.add(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(stringLatitudeDest), Double.parseDouble(stringLongitudeDest)));

                                if (MarkerPoints.size() >= 2) {
                                    LatLng origin = MarkerPoints.get(0);
                                    LatLng dest = MarkerPoints.get(1);
                                    // Getting URL to the Google Directions API
                                    String url = getUrl(origin, dest);
                                    Log.d("onMapClick", url.toString());
                                    FetchUrl fetchUrl = new FetchUrl();
                                    // Start downloading json data from Google Directions API
                                    fetchUrl.execute(url);
                                    //move map camera
                                    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(origin, 14.0f));
                                }
                            }
                        }else {
                            snackbar = Snackbar.make(mainFrameLayout, "No Co-ordinates due to"+json.getString("msg"), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                            snackbar.getView().setBackgroundColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark);
                            TextView mainTextView = (TextView) (snackbar.getView()).findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
                            mainTextView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                            snackbar.show();
                        }
                    }catch (JSONException je){
                        je.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    snackbar = Snackbar.make(mainFrameLayout, error.toString(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                    snackbar.getView().setBackgroundColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark);
                    TextView mainTextView = (TextView) (snackbar.getView()).findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
                    mainTextView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                    snackbar.show();
                }
            }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
            String stringDeviceModel = Build.MODEL;
            String stringDeviceSeries = Build.SERIAL;
            String stringDeviceOS = Build.VERSION.RELEASE;

            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("imei",stringIMEI);
            params.put("model",stringDeviceModel);
            params.put("series",stringDeviceSeries);
            params.put("os",stringDeviceOS);
            params.put("latitude",stringLatitudeOrigin);
            params.put("longitude",stringLongitudeOrigin);
            params.put("datetime",stringCurrentDate);
            return params;
        }
    };
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}

public void SaveRouteVolleyRequest(String route){
    final String paramRoute = route;
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Constants.SAVEROUTEAPI_URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);
                        if (json.getString("success").equals("1")) {
                            snackbar = Snackbar.make(mainFrameLayout, json.getString("msg"), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                            snackbar.getView().setBackgroundColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark);
                            TextView mainTextView = (TextView) (snackbar.getView()).findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
                            mainTextView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                            snackbar.show();
                        }else {
                            snackbar = Snackbar.make(mainFrameLayout,"No Co-ordinates due to"+json.getString("msg"), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                            snackbar.getView().setBackgroundColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark);
                            TextView mainTextView = (TextView) (snackbar.getView()).findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
                            mainTextView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                            snackbar.show();
                        }
                    }catch (JSONException je){
                        je.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    snackbar = Snackbar.make(mainFrameLayout, error.toString(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                    snackbar.getView().setBackgroundColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark);
                    TextView mainTextView = (TextView) (snackbar.getView()).findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
                    mainTextView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                    snackbar.show();
                }
            }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("device_id",sharedPreferences.getString("device_id",""));
            params.put("route",paramRoute);
            return params;
        }
    };
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}

public boolean isConnectingToInternet(Context context){
    ConnectivityManager connectivity=(ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (connectivity != null)
    {
        NetworkInfo info[]=connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
        if(info!=null)
        {
            for(int i=0;i<info.length;i++)
                if(info[i].getState()== NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)
                    return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The problem is

```
if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
    }
```

in your `onLocationChanged` method.
You are removing location updates the moment you get your first location update as `mGoogleApiClient != null` is true.
Move the `removeLocationUpdates` to your `onDestroy` block and everything should work.